# How to share global variable between two servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, global-variables, linked-server

As in the title I would like to share global variable ***@@Version*** between two linked servers in SQL Server.

How could i do that with query like

```
SET @Ver = SUBSTRING (@@VERSION, 22, 7)
```

Comment: what do you mean by `share` ? You want to access the `@@Version` on the remote server via `linked server`  ?

Comment: yes, exactly. I would like to get version of 2nd (linked) server by command @@Version running on 1st server

Answer (score 2):

You can't share variables between two servers. If you have the server's set up as linked servers, however, you could use `OPENQUERY`. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(OtherServer,
               'SELECT @@VERSION AS Version');
```

Where `OtherServer` is the name of the Linked Server object of your other server (which might not necessarily be the name of the server). If you don't have them as linked Servers, you could instead use `OPENROWSET`. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                'Server=OtherServer;Trusted_Connection=YES;',
                'SELECT @@VERSION AS Version');
```

Where `OtherServer` is the actual name of the other server. If the instance is named, you'll need to include that as well. For example `Server=sqldev\Sandbox` would be the `Sandbox` named instance running on the Server `sqldev`.

If you want to set this to the value of a variable, then you'd do it like any other assignment:

```
DECLARE @SQLVersion varchar(500);

SELECT @SQLVersion = [Version]
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                'Server=OtherServer;Trusted_Connection=YES;',
                'SELECT @@VERSION AS Version');

PRINT @SQLVersion;
```

Comment: Could we somehow change Select statement to Set in above queries?

Comment: @Rocket128 not sure what you mean. Perhaps my edit helps? You can't `SET` the value of `@@VERSION`, so if it doesn't (help), you need to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I thought of was a table and linked servers. On server A, create a global_variables table and store the values in that table in a format that works for you. Then, on server B, you can set a local variable equal to the value in your global_variables table by querying the new table on server A.

If you need to make changes to the variable while on B, you can then just update the global_variables table on A from B since the servers are linked.